# $\mathbb{P}(X\in A) = 0 \implies \mathbb{E}(X1_A)=0$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ a real random variable. We assume $X\in L^1$ but not any further information (such as existence of a density). I would like to prove that: $$\mathbb{P}(X\in A) = 0 \implies \mathbb{E}\left(X1_A(X)\right)=0. $$
It looks quite natural and is perhaps easy to prove, so just a hint would be great.

Comment: Your formulation is wrong.  For example, if $X$ is the constant $7$ and $A$ is the interval $[0,1]$.  A correct statement would be $$\mathbb P(A) = 0 \implies \mathbb{E}(X1_A)=0.$$

Comment: It's not wrong. That makes perfect sense,  treating $X=7$ as a degenerate random variable. It's typical notation.

Comment: @Xiaomi Sure but the assertion fails to hold for the given example.

Comment: Your statement looks odd. When you write $X \in A$, you imply that $A$ is some measurable subset of the reals. When you write $1_A$, you imply $A$ is a measurable set in the probability space.

Comment: @Calculon $P(X \in A)$ is short hand notation for $P(X^{-1}(A))$. While $1_A$ is short hand notation for $1\{ X(\omega) \in A\}$.

Comment: @Xiaomi $A$ would still have to be a subset of the reals in your second notation.

Comment: It's a subset of the reals in both...

Comment: $1_A$ cannot be a short hand notation for $1_{X(\omega) \in A}$. $1_A$ already means $1_{\omega \in A}$.

Comment: In this context, $1_A$ is intended as short hand for $1\{X(\omega) \in A\}$. This is the notation used in standard probability textbooks: see for example Probability: Theory and Examples by Durrett

Comment: Indeed, in the notation $1_A$, I didn't specify that it is valued in $X$ : $1_A(X)=1_{X(\omega)\in A}$.

Comment: So could you please correct your question? (And be careful about your phrasing ... "it is valued in $X$" doesn't make any sense... it's the random variable $X$ which takes values in a certain set...)

Comment: Well English is not my native language. What I meant is that the variable of the indicator function is valued in $X(\omega)$, which means that it is $1$ if $X(\omega)$ is in $A$, and $0$ otherwise. Anyway I edited the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before anyone says this is wrong - read the comment chain under OP's post on notation

here $P(X \in A ) = P( X^{-1}(A))$ while $1_A = 1\{ X(\omega) \in A \}$ are short hand notation used by OP's probability course.

---

By definition of expected value of indicator random variables,

$$P(X \in A) = 0 \implies \mathbb{E}1_A = 0 \implies \int_\Omega 1_A dP = 0 \implies \int_A dP = 0$$

Since $X \in L^1$ we know $\int_\Omega |X| dP < M < \infty$.

This implies that for any set $A$ we can find a finite constant $M_A$ such that $\int_A |X| dP \leq M_A \int_A dP$.

Hence, we have

$$\int_A X dP \geq -M_A \int_A dP = 0$$

$$\int_A X dP \leq M_A \int_A dP = 0$$

So we have:

$$\int_A X dP \leq 0$$ $$\int_A X dP \geq 0 $$

Which must mean

$$E X 1_A = \int_A X dP = 0$$

Comment: Why would $\mathbb{P}(X \in A)=0$ imply $\mathbb{E}(1_A)=0$? That's plain wrong...

Comment: $1_A$ is short hand for $1 \{ X (\omega) \in A \}$. See the discussion under OP's post. $E1_A = \int_\Omega 1_A dP = \int_A dP = P(X(\omega) \in A)$...

Comment: If you use this (in my opinion very stupid) shorthand, then you should clarify this in your answer.... otherwise the implication is just wrong.

Comment: Ok thank you. So I need to understand why $\mathbb{P}(A)=0\implies \int_A X(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)=0$.

Comment: No, it's not wrong. It's the notation OP uses (and likely his class uses...) and hence makes most sense to answer his question using it. This notation is used in many popular probability textbooks. You can have your opinion on whether it's good, but that's just an opinion.

Comment: The answer should be accessible to anyone who has attended a proability/measure theory course, and not only to persons who are familiar with some particular notation which is used in certain books; for this reason the answer fails to be helpful. And yeah, that's just my opinion.

Comment: Fair enough, I added a quick note at the top of my answer.

Comment: Your proof is still not right. You did not show why $P(A) = 0$ implies $E[X1_A] = 0$, which would be the whole point of this assertion (setting aside the issues with your notation).

Comment: Well feel free to post a correct answer then. I cannot delete it since it's been accepted. BTW being needlessly abrasive over the notation, even after I've attempted to accomodate your issues with it, is not needed and does not help anyone.